# How bad is it to not mention a child when booking hotels?

Tags: travel

My wife and I have 5 kids (the oldest is 7, the youngest is a newborn). This makes us a family of 7. I have always been willing to list all of our kids when booking hotel rooms even though this has often required us to go from a regular room to a suite even though my kids always seem to find their way into our bed at night.

Now that we have a new one, we are finding it nearly impossible to find a hotel that takes 7 even for a suite. Some do go for up to 8, but in general we are finding no rooms available that fit our party size. The few that we have found are significantly more expensive than other rooms/suites. As our newborn is not in need of any bed/services and does not eat breakfast (he is nursing), is it a big deal if we don't declare him and stick with a typical suite?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Parenting.SE! Did you already check out [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/), where your question may get more and better answers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is only tangentially related to parenting.  It is more of a "how do I legally/morally/ethically deal with this hotel problem" question.

Comment: Your question is more about hotel protocol than parenting.  You may get a more detailed answer by asking the Travel Stack Exchange. https://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Chris, I'd suggest revising this question somewhat.  Right now it sounds like you're asking for advice on breaking rules, which isn't exactly our sort of thing; I'd suggest considering in particular whether you're asking this here because you want the advice of *other parents* who have faced a similar situation, or whether you're really asking about hotel rules. If the latter, then we can migrate this question to [travel.se] if you like.  If the former, you may want to reword the question some to make it clear you're asking for general advice how to solve this problem (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) rather than focusing on the specific solution you're thinking about.

Comment: I’d also add your country/location of travel, if you do repost on "travel" SE. In the UK, at least, it’s often better value for money to look at self catered lodges. You get a whole house (with a washing machine!) for not much more than a hotel room.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on jurisdiction, room capacity may be determined by fire code. You could put yourself in a situation where the proprietor is unable to serve your party, costing him the income from the room and yourself a nights accommodation.